# Trying to alter the url opened in a popup based on changing values of the url

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to alter the URL based on the values selected in the 4 drop down menus available.

Here is my attempt at javascript to solve the problem. However, I beleive I am breaking some coding rules but am not experienced enough to fix it.

```
<script>

    function link_ch(t) {
        var sel_el = t.options[t.selectedIndex]
        document.getElementById('down_st').onclick = 'http://waterwatch.usgs.gov/download/?gt=map&ofmt=kmr&x=0&st=' + sel_el.value
    }

  </script>
```

And here is the html code for the drop down menu and the button to open the pop up.

```
<header>
    <div id='map_container' style="margin-top: 100px; border: 0px solid red; text-align: center;">
      <div id="xbuilder">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <div>
                  United States: 
                  <span data-tooltip='Choose a US state'>
                    <select name='usst' id='usst' size='1' onchange='set_st(this);' >
                      <option value=''>States</option>
                      </option>
                      <option value='al'>Alabama</option>
                      <option value='ak'>Alaska</option>
                      <option value='az'>Arizona</option>
                      <option value='ar'>Arkansas</option>
                      <option value='ca'>California</option>
                      <option value='co'>Colorado</option>
                      <option value='ct'>Connecticut</option>
                      <option value='de'>Delaware</option>
                      <option value='dc'>District of Columbia</option>
                      <option value='fl'>Florida</option>
                      <option value='ga'>Georgia</option>
                      <option value='hi'>Hawaii</option>
                      <option value='id'>Idaho</option>
                      <option value='il'>Illinois</option>
                      <option value='in'>Indiana</option>
                      <option value='ia'>Iowa</option>
                      <option value='ks'>Kansas</option>
                      <option value='ky'>Kentucky</option>
                      <option value='la'>Louisiana</option>
                      <option value='me'>Maine</option>
                      <option value='md'>Maryland</option>
                      <option value='ma'>Massachusetts</option>
                      <option value='mi'>Michigan</option>
                      <option value='mn'>Minnesota</option>
                      <option value='ms'>Mississippi</option>
                      <option value='mo'>Missouri</option>
                      <option value='mt'>Montana</option>
                      <option value='ne'>Nebraska</option>
                      <option value='nv'>Nevada</option>
                      <option value='nh'>New Hampshire</option>
                      <option value='nj'>New Jersey</option>
                      <option value='nm'>New Mexico</option>
                      <option value='ny'>New York</option>
                      <option value='nc'>North Carolina</option>
                      <option value='nd'>North Dakota</option>
                      <option value='oh'>Ohio</option>
                      <option value='ok'>Oklahoma</option>
                      <option value='or'>Oregon</option>
                      <option value='pa'>Pennsylvania</option>
                      <option value='ri'>Rhode Island</option>
                      <option value='sc'>South Carolina</option>
                      <option value='sd'>South Dakota</option>
                      <option value='tn'>Tennessee</option>
                      <option value='tx'>Texas</option>
                      <option value='ut'>Utah</option>
                      <option value='vt'>Vermont</option>
                      <option value='va'>Virginia</option>
                      <option value='wa'>Washington</option>
                      <option value='wv'>West Virginia</option>
                      <option value='wi'>Wisconsin</option>
                      <option value='wy'>Wyoming</option>
                      <option value='pr'>Puerto Rico</option>
                    </select>
                  </span>
                  <span data-tooltip='Choose a US water resource region'>
                    <select name='ushuc' id='ushuc' size='1' onchange='set_st(this);' >
                      <option value=''>Water Res. Region</option>
                      <option value='01'>01 New England</option>
                      <option value='02'>02 Mid Atlantic</option>
                      <option value='03'>03 South Atlantic-Gulf</option>
                      <option value='04'>04 Great Lakes</option>
                      <option value='05'>05 Ohio</option>
                      <option value='06'>06 Tennessee</option>
                      <option value='07'>07 Upper Mississippi</option>
                      <option value='08'>08 Lower Mississippi</option>
                      <option value='09'>09 Souris-Red-Rainy</option>
                      <option value='10'>10 Missouri</option>
                      <option value='11'>11 Arkansas-White-Red</option>
                      <option value='12'>12 Texas-Gulf</option>
                      <option value='13'>13 Rio Grande</option>
                      <option value='14'>14 Upper Colorado</option>
                      <option value='15'>15 Lower Colorado</option>
                      <option value='16'>16 Great Basin</option>
                      <option value='17'>17 Pacific Northwest</option>
                      <option value='18'>18 California</option>
                      <option value='19'>19 Alaska</option>
                      <option value='20'>20 Hawaii</option>
                      <option value='21'>21 Puerto Rico</option>
                    </select>
                  </span>
                </div>
                    <button class="button" onClick="window.open('http://waterwatch.usgs.gov/download/?gt=map&st=&ofmt=kmr&x=0');" id="down_st" ><span class="icon">Download</span></button>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <div>
                  Canada:
                  <span data-tooltip='Choose a Canadian province'>
                    <select name='nus' id='nus' size='1' onchange='set_st(this);' >
                      <option value=''>Provinces</option>
                      <option value='zab'>Alberta</option>
                      <option value='zbc'>British Columbia</option>
                      <option value='zmb'>Manitoba</option>
                      <option value='znb'>New Brunswick</option>
                      <option value='znl'>Newfoundland and Labrador</option>
                      <option value='zns'>Nova Scotia</option>
                      <option value='znt'>Northwest Territories</option>
                      <option value='znu'>Nunavut</option>
                      <option value='zon'>Ontario</option>
                      <option value='zpe'>Prince Edward Island</option>
                      <option value='zqc'>Quebec</option>
                      <option value='zsk'>Saskatchewan</option>
                      <option value='zyt'>Yukon</option>
                    </select>
                  </span>
                  <span data-tooltip='Choose a Canadian river basin'>
                    <select name='nhuc' id='nhuc' size='1' onchange='set_st(this);' >
                      <option value=''>Canadian River Basins</option>
                      <option value='z01'>01 Maritime Provinces Drainage</option>
                      <option value='z02'>02 St.Lawrence River Drainage</option>
                      <option value='z03'>03 Northern Quebec Drainage</option>
                      <option value='z04'>04 Southwest Hudson Bay Drainage</option>
                      <option value='z05'>05 Nelson River Drainage</option>
                      <option value='z06'>06 Western Hudson Bay Drainage</option>
                      <option value='z07'>07 Great Slave Lake Drainage</option>
                      <option value='z08'>08 Pacific Drainage</option>
                      <option value='z09'>09 Yukon River Drainage</option>
                      <option value='z10'>10 Arctic Drainage</option>
                      <option value='z11'>11 Mississippi River Drainage</option>
                    </select>
                  </span>
                </div>
                <div style='margin-left: 10px; float: right;' data-tooltip="Click to view a map of specified region."><input name="go" value="Go" type="submit"/></div>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
      </center>
    </div>
  </header>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place the jQuery in `No wrap in body`. Use this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pandeyvishal1986/0m5s3toy/2/#&togetherjs=PThgaHjnNH)

JS:

```
function set_st(t) {
        var sel_el = t.options[t.selectedIndex];
        var link = "http://waterwatch.usgs.gov/download/?gt=map&st="+sel_el.value+"&ofmt=kmr&x=0";
        //alert(link);
        document.getElementById('down_st').onclick = function(){window.open(
  link,  '_blank' )
  };
    }
```

Comment: What if I already have a function set_st(t) is there a`nother way to do this

Comment: change the name of the `function` or Call that function from another one :)

Comment: Not sure why but when I chaneg the function name the script doesnt do anything. Oh and here is the other function I am reffering to you if this helps.                                                                                                                                      function set_st(t) {
   var sel_el = t.options[t.selectedIndex]
     document.getElementById('my-iframe').src 'http://watermonitor.gov/naww/index.php?st=' + sel_el.value
    }

Comment: Can you please post a fresh question with updated `html` :)

Comment: Already did right here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40915641/two-javascript-functions-with-the-same-name-referencing-values

Comment: just merge the code in single `function`. don't create two functions with same name

Comment: OK thank you for your help I will look into doing this